# Differentiation of a function with respect to an extra variable

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I was looking at the following answer to a related rates problem, and it got me thinking: **How is that the variable $t$ comes up in the bottom differential?** If I multiply both sides by $dt$ and then divide by one of the remaining differentials I get the results of an implicit differentiation, but I was led to believe that one could not multiply and divide differentials so carelessly, and that doing so is a part of non-standard analysis. Is there a more standard way of doing this (maybe the Leibniz Chain Rule?) or am I just missing something entirely? I was always told to solve problems this way, and have... I just feel like my learning could have been a bit more rigid!

> HINT:
>
> You start with Pythagorean Theorem,
>
> $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
>
> Then you take the derivative of both sides, and divide both sides by
>   2,
>
> $$2a\frac{da}{dt} + 2b\frac{db}{dt} = 2c\frac{dc}{dt}$$
>   $$a\frac{da}{dt} + b\frac{db}{dt} = c\frac{dc}{dt}$$

Comment: Are you asking why we can differentiate implicitly? Or why we can treat differentials as fractions and still get a correct result (sometimes)?

Comment: @BenLongo I've always seen implicit differentiation done with making one function in terms of the other; for example, if I have $xy=1$ then I can say that $y$ is a function of $x$ and use the chain rule. However, no variable $t$ comes up in these implicit differentiation, hence my confusion as to what we get above. I can show that it works treating differentials as fractions, so an answer that explains why this works will do, but I would prefer a more direct route. (I'm aware I don't make much sense in all likelihood, and I'll edit accordingly as some of my confusion is cleared up.)

Comment: With related rates, the sides of the triangle are actually changing with time and thus are functions of time so we can differentiate with respect to time. It may be clearer to write $$a(t)^2+b(t)^2=c(t)^2$$ then applying the chain rule makes sense. 
$$a(t)\frac{da}{dt}+b(t)\frac{db}{dt}=c(t)\frac{dc}{dt}$$

Comment: @BenLongo Ah, so we make each variable a parametric function in terms of a parameter $t$ and then apply the chain rule to each function? I think I get it now... makes a lot of sense. Feel free to make that an answer if so and I'll mark it as correct. As a follow up though, if I'm correct it seems that we would not necessarily know what the formula for each function would be, just that it would be in terms of $t$... is it fine to do so in a non-constructive manner and keep going, allowing this to be generalized?

Comment: You are correct that we don't necessarily know the functions, but the problem will usually tell you the rates and or quantities at time $t$ and tell you to find something else with that information even if the functions are never given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In related rates problems, the variables of the problem are usually changing with respect to a common parameter, usually time. Thus, every variable in the problem becomes a function of time. In your example, the sides of the triangle $a$, $b$ and $c$ become functions of time $a(t)$, $b(t)$ and $c(t)$. This is where the $t$ in the bottom differential comes from. We know that

$$a(t)^2+b(t)^2=c(t)^2$$

When we differentiate with respect to $t$, the chain rule still applies and we obtain

$$2a(t)\frac{da}{dt}+2b(t)\frac{db}{dt}=2c(t)\frac{dc}{dt}$$
$$a(t)\frac{da}{dt}+b(t)\frac{db}{dt}=c(t)\frac{dc}{dt}$$

However, we usually don't write the variables explicitly as functions of time as I have done here; it is implied that they are functions of time as you have notated in your question.